# SQL Server 2008 changing query value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In a query I want to present the employee's monthly salary. I want to present a salary of 1500 in the query if the result is below that, if not I want to keep the sum I got in the query.

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to use a `case` statement.  Something like this:

```
select (case when salary < 1500 then 1500 else salary end) as salary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select

case when salary<1500 then 1500 else salary end
, column2
,column3
from mytable
```